# How to use add_submenu_page() for editors?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, admin-menu, add-submenu-page

Currently I load a custom WooCommerce sub menu point in an own plugin like:

```
// Add an additional submenupoint
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_mycustom_menupoint');
function register_mycustom_menupoint() {
    add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Name on Menubutton', 'Name on Menubutton', 'manage_options', 'custom-submenu-page', 'dsrv_init_backend' ); 
}

function call_this_function_name(){
    // ...
}
```

But this is only available for WP users at administration level. After searching the internet I tried to use `edit.php?post_type=shop_order` instead of `woocommerce` but then the menu point disappears. What do I have to change to fix it?

Woocommerce: **2.6.4**, Wordpress: **4.6.11**

Comment: I'd be more worried about WordPress and WooCommerce being out of date. I'd consider updating those first before worrying about sub menus...

Comment: Sure ... do like to pay for our customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `edit_posts` capability instead of `manage_options`. `manage_options` is an administrator level capability. Try the following code -

```
add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'Name on Menubutton', 'Name on Menubutton', 'edit_posts', 'custom-submenu-page', 'dsrv_init_backend' );
```

Comment: More about Wordpress capabilities: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities